# Iterating a list and making it follow a certain condition

Tags: python

I'm supposed to take a function that takes 3 string arguments and checks how many of those arguments are either philosophy, math, literature, or programming and returns the number.

```
def count_subjects(subject_1: str, subject_2: str, subject_3: str)->int:
    nm1=subject_1
    nm2=subject_2
    nm3=subject_3
    count=[nm1,nm2,nm3]
    n=["philosophy","programming", "literature", "math"]
   
    for i in count:
    
        if i in count and n:
            print (count)
         
            return len(count)
        else:
            count.remove(i)
            print (count)
            return len(count)
```

This is what I have so far but it will stop after evaluating the first argument.

So, if I have `print(count_subjects(philosophy, mat, literature))`, it will run the code as if all the arguments fulfilled the condition.

Comment: `return` exits the loop so only the first one gets processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- `return` exits the loop so only one check is done
- `if i in count and n:` should be `if i in n` since `i` is always in `count`

Try this code:

```
def count_subjects(subject_1: str, subject_2: str, subject_3: str)->int:
    nm1=subject_1
    nm2=subject_2
    nm3=subject_3
    count=[nm1,nm2,nm3]
    n=["philosophy","programming", "literature", "math"]

    total = 0
    
    for i in count:
        if i in n:
           print (total)
           total += 1
           
    return total
```